# Readable values in on axis with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with Matplotlib and trying to plot a combo box with bars and lines. Below you can see my data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

# Data
data = {
         'Year': ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'],
         'Rate':[10,10,9,7,5,5,5,5,5,5],
         'ChangeRate_1':[7,-50,24,150,8,10,60,5,180,5],
         'ChangeRate_2':[7,6,-3,1,8,5,8,5,15,5],
         
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year',
                                   'Rate',
                                   'ChangeRate_1',
                                   'ChangeRate_2'
                                   
                                   ])
df
```

Below you can see code :

```
# Ploting combo plot
fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 5))
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()
ax_3 = ax_2.twinx()   ### <---- Problem is probably here 
cmap = get_cmap('tab10')

ax_1.bar(df['Year'], df['Rate'], label = 'Rate', color = cmap(0))
ax_2.plot(df['Year'], df['ChangeRate_1'], label = 'ChangeRate_2', color = cmap(0.1),linewidth = '3.5')
ax_3.plot(df['Year'], df['ChangeRate_2'], label = 'ChangeRate_2', color = cmap(0.2),linewidth = '3.5')

handles_1, labels_1 = ax_1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_2, labels_2 = ax_2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_3, labels_3 = ax_3.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax_1.set_ylim(0, 16)
ax_2.set_ylim(-50,180)

ax_1.legend(handles = handles_1 + handles_2 + labels_3, 
            labels = labels_1 + labels_2 + labels_3, 
            loc = 'upper right', 
            shadow = True)
ax_1.grid(axis = 'y')
ax_1.set_title('Comparison of revenues',fontsize=11)

ax_1.set_ylabel('Rate')
ax_2.set_ylabel('ChangeRate_1')
ax_3.set_ylabel('ChangeRate_2')

ax_1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
plt.savefig('ComparisonOfRevenues.pdf')  
plt.show()
```

The above code produces a plot that is shown below.

[image]

As shown in the above plot, values for the `y-axis` for the left and for the right side overlap with values and are not readable.

For the left side, the scale for the 'Rate' should be in the range of 0 to 16, while for the right side, for ChangeRate_1 and ChangeRate_2, from  -50 to 180.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantiation of the third Axes object with `ax_3 = ax_2.twinx()` can be circumvented by using just one extra y-axis on the right and plotting `ChangeRate_1` and `ChangeRate_2` on that axis keeping the (right) y-axis label as `ChangeRate` and then assigning correct labels to the lines.

[image]

Code:

```
fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()

cmap = get_cmap('tab10')

ax_1.bar(df['Year'], df['Rate'], label='Rate', color=cmap(0))
ax_2.plot(df['Year'], df['ChangeRate_1'], label='ChangeRate_1', color=cmap(0.1), linewidth='3.5')
ax_2.plot(df['Year'], df['ChangeRate_2'], label='ChangeRate_2', color=cmap(0.2), linewidth='3.5')

handles_1, labels_1 = ax_1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_2, labels_2 = ax_2.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax_1.set_ylim(0, 16)
ax_2.set_ylim(-50,180)

ax_1.legend(handles=handles_1 + handles_2, labels=labels_1 + labels_2, 
loc='upper right', shadow=True)

ax_1.grid(axis='y')
ax_1.set_title('Comparison of revenues',fontsize=11)

ax_1.set_ylabel('Rate')
ax_2.set_ylabel('ChangeRate')

ax_1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
plt.show()
```